# To keep screen active (without locking) in Windows while running Selenium scripts

Tags: vbscript

I am running my Selenium scrips in Windows machine, but during execution after some time the screen gets locked.

I have even set `Never` for `Power & Sleep` under `Settings`. But still my laptop screen gets locked during execution.

I want to run all my scripts for hours together without getting my laptop screen locked or in sleep mode.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Might get you started: https://learn2automate.blog/2013/11/22/how-to-prevent-system-from-unlocking-during-script-run/

Comment: Thanks ! But i don't have admin privileges to do that.

Comment: Is your laptop managed by admin ? If that is the case then your admin defaults are overriding your personal power settings. Just check if there is an app for your admin, this app will have a settings page from where you can change the power settings. Contact admin otherwise.

Comment: That learn2automate.blog entry appears to be a dead link.

Answer (score 4):

A simple vb script will help you resolve this. Create a .vbs file and paste the below code

```
set wsc = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Do
    'one minute
    WScript.Sleep(60*1000)
    wsc.SendKeys("{NUMLOCK}")
Loop
```

The vbs script clicks Num Lock for every one minute and keeps the session active. Trigger that and the system will not get locked

**Make sure that your Automation run will not get effected by pressing Num Lock**

Comment: I have even tried that but pressing NUMLOCK affecting my script execution. ANy other ways to keep screen active?

Answer (score 0):

Top answer is awesome, but I also needed the script to be hidden.

Here is my batch file to open the window silently:

```
cmd /c powershell -Nop -NonI -Nologo -WindowStyle Hidden "Write-Host"
@echo off
cscript //NoLogo //B C:\Users\usr19\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\vbs.vbs
```

And here is my script based on the top answer:

```
Set fso = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set stdout = fso.GetStandardStream (1)
set wsc = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Do
    WScript.Sleep(60*5000)
    wsc.SendKeys("{NUMLOCK}")
    stdout.WriteLine "key pressed"
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows [**PowerToys**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) has an app called Awake. There is both GUI and CLI option.

**No admin privileges required.** You can run it as a standard user. (Checkout per user installer)

> PowerToys Awake is a utility tool for Windows designed to keep a
> computer awake without having to manage its power & sleep settings.
> This behavior can be helpful when running time-consuming tasks,
> ensuring that the computer does not go to sleep or turn off its
> screens.

[image]

Checkout below links for more details.

- https://awake.den.dev/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/awake